# DatabaseContext delay to update database

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have an issue when I use Code First EF. When I want to insert an User with its Permissions, the user insert well, but in inserting Permissions just after insert user, I see this exception :

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.UserPermissions_dbo.Users_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "DATABASE", table "dbo.Users", column 'UserId'.

Here my code :

```
public class User
{
    public short UserId { get; set; }
    public string  Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class UserPermission
{
    public int UserPermissionId { get; set; }
    public short UserId { get; set; }
    public short PermissionEnum { get; set; }
    public bool IsPermitted { get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

And final code to insert is :

```
    private void ConfirmButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var user = new User { Username = "myUsername", Password = "12"};

                    using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            dbContext.Users.AddOrUpdate(user);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        SaveUserPermissions(user);

    }

    private void SaveUserPermissions(User user)
    {


        var userPermissionsToSave = new ObservableCollection<UserPermission>();

        foreach (var permission in ThisUserPermissionData.UserPermissions)
        {
                var newUserPermission = new UserPermission();

                newUserPermission.UserId = PageModel.UserId;
                newUserPermission.UserPermissionTypeEnum = 4;                    
                userPermissionsToSave.Add(newUserPermission);

        }

        using (var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            dbContext.UserPermissions.AddOrUpdate(userPermissionsToSave.ToArray());
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Note that when I set breakpoint after save user, the code perform correctly. But in normal mode, my code has that exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't it be `user.UserId` instead of `PageModel.UserId` here: `newUserPermission.UserId = PageModel.UserId;`?

Comment: @ASh sorry, the code is user.UserId. In fact the code is different but I Copy part of it for simplicity.